# Show $\|\cdot\|$ is a norm of the space of $C^1[0,1]$

Tags: functional-analysis

Let $C^1([0,1])$ be the space of all functions having continuous derivatives. For each $f \in C^1([0,1])$, set

$$\|f\| = \left(\int_{0}^{1} (|f|^2 + |f'|^2) dx \right)^{1/2}$$

Show that $\|\cdot\|$ is a norm of the space of $C^1([0,1])$.

I mainly want to know to answer this question do I simply need to show the following properties: positivity, non-degenerate, homogeneity & the triangle inequality?

Comment: Hello, welcome to Math.SE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or be (temporarily) closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/xQWVb) will help you recognise and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Answer (score 2):

Positivity,non-degenerate, homogeneity are obvious.We can prove the triangle inequality by using **Minkowski's inequality.**
The inequality is very popular,so please look into it yourself.

Answer (score 1):

It suffices to remark that 
$$<f,g>=\int_0^1(fg+f'g')$$
is an inner product on $C^1([0,1])$.

Comment: I presume that this is the real case.